# Which event occur after clicking on edit button in gridview and before gridview_prerender and gridview_databound

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

It's take much time to start edit data after clicking on edit button. Edit button is generated by command AutoGenerateEditButton. In code i put points in every event but I can't find events between clicking on edit button and gridview_databound.

When I try add event OnRowCommand I get error: `'ASP.details_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'tableResults_RowCommand' and no extension method 'tableResults_RowCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.details_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: did you test gridview_rowdatabound, gridview_rowcommand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Events occur between `click on edit button` and `gridview_databound`
These are :-
**RowEditing**- fires when edit event is generated i.e when editindex >-1
**RowUpdating** :- This is fired when you click on update.
**Rowupdate** : fires when update has been commited.

**Your concern event is `RowEditing`**